# interview questions - little help

Tags: c++, arrays

i ran into thos quesiton in a google search.... they look pretty common, but i couldn't find a decent answer. any tips/links ?

1.Remove duplicates in array in O(n) without extra array

2.Write a program whose printed output is an exact copy of the source. Needless to say, merely echoing the actual source file is not allowed.

Comment: How .exe file can print out C++ source file without echoing source file?

Comment: I hate questions like number one. It really makes no sense to ask questions like that and make people feel dumb. In my practice - they will ask such algorithmic questions just to hire you to write GUI

Comment: What I hate about these sorts of questions is that they have no practical purpose and don't demonstrate anything about the candidate except that they have googled "interview questions" the day before. They are lazy things to ask and I would be wary of a person hiring who read anything into them about my true ability as a programmer. These questions, especially the second one, are just BS.  If you come across it in your interview ask them for a practical scenario in the role you have applied for in which that problem arises. It's like asking bricklayers if they can juggle bricks.

Comment: @Captain Comic: I wouldn't hire a GUI programmer without testing what he knew of other parts of programming -- not least algorithms and time complexity. That's very relevant for a GUI programmer, unless you *like* apps that take 20 seconds to populate a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(1) isn't possible unless the array is presorted. The basic answer is to keep two pointers into the array, one walking forward searching for unequal elements, and one trailing pointer. When the forward pointer encounters an unequal element, it copies it into the trailing pointer and increments the trailing pointer.

(2) I don't have one handy. This sounds like a pretty terrible interview question. In most interpreted languages, a 0 byte (empty) source file is valid input, and prints out nothing.. that should count.

Comment: Heh, +1 for your answer to #2. Best way to answer such a pointless question :p

Comment: if the array is not presorted, it could be easily sorted in place using heap sort.

Comment: @Anna the question said "in O(n) time". Sorting the array can't be done faster than O(nlogn); hence my comment that the array must be presorted

Answer (score 5):

For (1), you probably need more constraints than you've given. However, look up *radix sort*.

For (2), look up *quine*.

Comment: Radix sort won't work because you aren't allowed an external array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to implement radix sort in-place.  I could be wrong, but I'm thinking it through in my mind right now and can't see where I'd run into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question google for quine, you will find lots of answers!

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to one is using a hashtable to store seen elements and assigning each non-duplicated one to an appropriate value at the start of the array (this would leave several irrelevant ones at the end) - this would take O(n) time but is not the sort of thing you want to have to write during a job interview. Alternatively, as long as the list is sorted just check whether each element is equal to the previous.

For 2 would just manually printing the content's of the file be allowed? (if so the question is more than a little bit pointless).

Edit:

Here is a fast Perl version of my solution to the first - in c++ you would have to create the hash manually:

```
# Return an unsorted version of an array without duplicates
sub unsortedDedup {
    my %seen, my @return;

    map {
        $seen{$_} = 1 
        && push @return, $_ 
        unless (defined $seen{$_})
    } @_;

    @return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The STL is often not an option in such interview questions, but here's one way to do #1 using the STL, although it does incur an additional sort (as explained by [Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957523/interview-questions-little-help/1957554#1957554)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1 };
  int * end = a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

  std::sort(a, end);          // O(n log n)
  end = std::unique(a, end);  // O(n)

  std::copy(a, end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
$ ./a.out 
1 2 3 4
```

`std::unique()` is generally implemented using the same technique Terry described in his answer (see `bits/stl_algo.h` in g++'s STL implementation for an example of how to implement it).

Answer (score 0):

For #2, there are a number of answers for different languages here: http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

There is also an alternative quine in c++ here: http://npcomplete.weebly.com/1/post/2010/02/self-reproducing-c-program-quine.html